# Deduce derived types polymorphically

Tags: java, design-patterns, polymorphism, clean-architecture

Whats the recommended design approach/alternative to the situation below:

```
BaseCalculator:
BaseType prepareData()
useData(BaseType)
```

Derived calculators use derived type to override base functionality -

```
DerivedCalculator1:
BaseType prepareData(){ return DerivedType1}
useData(BaseType t1){ DerivedType1 t=(DerivedType1)t1 //typecast  down and proceed....}

DerivedCalculator2
BaseType prepareData(){ return DerivedType2}
useData(BaseType t1){ DerivedType2 t=(DerivedType2)t1 //typecast down and proceed....}
```

Is there a design approach to avoid typecasting by the derived classes - as it always leaves the gate open for a run-time mishap?

Comment: You can use generics: `class BaseCalculator<T extends BaseType> { T prepareData(); void useData(T t)` etc.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to move the polymorphic behavior into the implementations of the `BaseType` rather than in the implementations of `BaseCalculator`. For example:

```
public interface BaseType {
    public void process(Calculator calc);
}

public class DerivedType1 implements BaseType {

    @Override
    public void process(Calculator calc) {
        // Do something specific to derived type 1
    }
}

public class DerivedType2 implements BaseType {

    @Override
    public void process(Calculator calc) {
        // Do something specific to derived type 2
    }
}

public class Calculator {

    public void doSomething(BaseType bt) {
        bt.process(this);
    }
}
```

If that type of solution is insufficient, a more complex solution is the [Visitor Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/visitor). The Visitor Pattern allows any arbitrary `BaseType` object to be handled by any arbitrary `BaseCalculator` using [double-dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch). The catch is that all `BaseCalculator` implementations must have an method to handle each of the `BaseType` implementations. For example:

```
public interface BaseType {
    public void process(Calculator calc);
}

public class DerivedType1 implements BaseType {

    @Override
    public void process(Calculator calc) {
        // Do something specific to derived type 1
    }
}

public class DerivedType2 implements BaseType {

    @Override
    public void process(Calculator calc) {
        // Do something specific to derived type 2
    }
}

public interface BaseCalculator {
    public void handle(DerivedType1 dt);
    public void handle(DerivedType2 dt);
}

public class DerviedCalculator1 implements BaseCalculator {

    @Override
    public void handle(DerivedType1 dt) {
        dt.process(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(DerivedType2 dt) {
        dt.process(this);
    }
}

public class DerviedCalculator2 implements BaseCalculator {

    @Override
    public void handle(DerivedType1 dt) {
        dt.process(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(DerivedType2 dt) {
        dt.process(this);
    }
}
```